# Comparing intergers within string values

Tags: php

I have some string values stored in a database table for the screen sizes of laptops like 14 inches,14.8 inches, 15.1 inches, 15.6 inches, 16 inches and so on. These values are being searched using an advanced search option which uses a range of values like:

```
less than 14 inches
14-15 inches
15-16 inches
16-18 inches
```

How can I use the above search criteria to get the values from the database to show me all the screen sizes that lie within the range:

```
15-16 inches
```

The results returned should be all records with 15.1 inches, 15.6 inches

I have tried using comparison operators but the correct results are not shown. It either shows the starting values or the ending values. Not the ones in between the range.

Comment: You will need to regex the numbers out of the strings, and THEN do the comparison.

Comment: Or you could store the units in a separate column. This way you could do a true comparison by calculating their lengths in reference to units, rather than unit-agnostic value.

Comment: Are your values stored as strings in the database, or floats?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numeric values as strings, especially if you intend to sort/search/compare them as numbers.

Comment: Dunno if this works, but you can try: `select *,id +0 as odr from my_table order by odr;`. This should convert id to int

Comment: @DainisAbols: It's not necessary, because with numeric comparison MySQL will convert string to numbers (not int but float) on the fly.

Comment: Is that for some database of some kind (I assumed MySQL in my answer but re-reading the question it isn't actually mentioned). How do you pass these options into your script?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 14, 15, 16, 18 are your 4 options and $myValue is the value you want to compare them with

Try:

```
$range = array(14, 15, 16, 18);
foreach ($range as $key => $val)
{
    // first option
    if ($myValue <$range[0])
        $option = 1;

    // last option
    else if($myValue > $range[count($range))
        $option = count($range)+1;

    // other options
    else if($myValue < $val && $myValue > $range[$key-1])
        $option = $key+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '15-16 inches';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` will be returned as an array with the following format:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '15',
    1 => '16',
  ),
)
```

From this, you can compare your database result against `$matches[0][0]` and `$matches[0][1]`.

Comment: `sscanf($str, '%d-%d inches', $from, $to);` - http://de.php.net/sscanf - gives you integers, directly. and it's more clear what it does ;)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the [`BETWEEN` comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for that:

```
SELECT * FROM test.inches WHERE text BETWEEN 15 AND 16;
```

To get all entries from that range. `BETWEEN` will also convert the string into a number.

```
3   15.1 inches 15.1
4   15.6 inches 15.6
5   16 inches   16
```

Alternatively to `BETWEEN` you can formulate two criteria and tell both need to be matched (`AND`):

```
SELECT * FROM test.inches WHERE text >= 15 AND text < 16;
                                `-- #1 --´  +  `-- #2 -´
```

This gives you then:

```
3   15.1 inches 15.1
4   15.6 inches 15.6
```

I hope this helps.

---

About casting (converting string to number here): In MySQL (at least the version I use here but this is common), you can convert the string to a number and then numerical compare against it by adding 0. A demonstration:

```
SELECT "15.1 inches" + 0 AS inches;
```

Returns a single row with the number;:

```
15.1
```

The same can be done when querying the database:

```
SELECT * FROM inches WHERE text + 0 BETWEEN 14 AND 15;
```

Take care that you originally should have stored the number as a number into the database. So you can introduce a new column and convert the existing date:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`inches` ADD COLUMN `number` FLOAT NULL  AFTER `text` ;
UPDATE inches SET number = text + 0;
```

You then can directly query from there without doing the conversion all the time:

```
SELECT * FROM inches WHERE number BETWEEN 14 AND 15;
```

That will allow you to create and index and really speed up the search in the future if necessary. But until then you already have normalized the data a bit more.